# Viewport2DVisual3D is invisible behind another Viewport2DVisual3D, even though the second visual is transparent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d, rendering

I have a transparent `Viewport2DVisual3D outer` that is wrapped around another `Viewport2DVisual3D inner`. When `outer` is added to the viewport before `inner`, `inner` is invisible (even though `outer` is transparent). If `inner` is added first, it works correctly.

Visuals are added to the viewport by the user, so the order in which they are added is unknown. I don't want to remove and re-add everything in the correct order every time the user adds a new visual if at all possible. Is there another way to make `inner` visible through `outer` regardless of the order that the visuals are added in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, re-ordering your Viewport2DVisual3D's from back-to-front (that is, for one to show up "behind" another transparent element, it must be added first) is precisely what you have to do.

See details [here at the wpf3d team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf3d/archive/2009/06/18/transparent-diffusematerials-and-depth-sorting.aspx).